# iPhone Mail stops being received after a while

Tags: iphone, email, troubleshooting, google-workspace, pop3

I've setup my iPhone with my Google Apps email account, and when it works it works brilliantly. It receives and sends email without a problem. However I've run into a problem with it that is making my phone really difficult to use for the purpose I bought it for (internet, email, SMS).

In my email settings I turn on POP access for all mail "**from now on**", and the iPhone picks up email for a couple of weeks. However, after a couple of weeks of usage, it downright refuses to get any new email. When I go into the Inbox on my phone I get emails from (at least) a week before. This is kind of frustrating as I have to use the browser method (via the browser) for all my mailing, which is awfully ineffective.

I can fix the problem by resetting the POP access on my email account to "from now on" again, but there's got to be a better way...

Has anyone else run into this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add your Gmail account as "Gmail"? According to Google, you need to add your Gmail account as a non-Gmail account in order for it to work. (Yes, backwards.)

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77702
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72454

As a better option, I'd suggest accessing GMail through your browser (then you retain labels and other features) and using the GPush iPhone app for push notifications.

Comment: So IMAP is the key... I'll have to give it a go. Thanks!